# Unable to add data binding to Angular 6 component

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I have a `component.ts` file like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-room-details-detail',    
  templateUrl: './room-details-detail.component.html',    
  styleUrls: ['./room-details-detail.component.css']
})

export class RoomDetailsDetailComponent implements OnInit {    
  private roomDetails = {};    
  private test = "Hello";

  constructor(private roomDetailsService: RoomDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.getRoomDetails();
  }

  public getRoomDetails() {    
    this.roomDetailsService.getRoomDetails().subscribe(data => {
      this.roomDetails = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

data looks like this: `{"floorArea":15.65333333,"volume":56.546333333,"paintRequired":9.768542}`

When I add:`<li>{{roomDetails.floorArea}}</li>` or `<li>{{test}}</li>`
to my component.html file I get this error on build:

The command `ng build --aot` exited with code 1.

I'm using `Visual Studio 15.7.6`

Comment: You need to make your `roomDetails` and `test` variables public

Comment: When I use  `ng build --aot` with the mistake you made, I get the following error: `ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.html(1,67): : Property 'test' is private and only accessible within class 'HomeComponent'`. which clearly explains what the problem is. What do you get as error message? Have you checked the error message? Because it helps **a lot**.

Comment: Noob error!!! OK, that worked for the test variable but I'm still getting the same error for roomDetails (I did try making it public before I added the test variable) I've tried <li>{{roomDetails.floorArea}}</li> and <li>{{floorArea}}</li>

Comment: Slightly different result using <li>{{floorArea}}</li>. It builds OK but the page is blank,

Comment: Using ng build --aot: ERROR in src\app\components\room-details-detail\room-details-detail.component.html(5,7): : Property 'floorArea' does not exist on type '{}'.

Answer (score 0):

@JB Nizet, thanks for your tip about using `ng build --aot`. This fixed it:

Changed `public roomDetails = {};`  to `public roomDetails;`